# Can't seed the database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently seed my database in Laravel, migrations works properly and I am able to see the tables in SQL workbench. But when I run the command `php artisan db:seed` nothing happens.

I can't find the cause of it. I'm pretty new to Laravel.

DB name is 'Laravel', the table name is 'books'.

Seeder Code:

```
 DB::table('books')->insert($books = [
        ['name' => 'Harry Potter', 'writer_name' => 'J.K. Rowling', 'isbn' => '9780739360385'],
        ['name' => 'Game of Thrones', 'writer_name' => 'George R.R. Martin', 'isbn' => '9780739308684'],
        ['name' => 'Harry Potter', 'writer_name' => 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 'isbn' => '9780563528807'],
        ['name' => 'The Lord of The Rings', 'writer_name' => 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 'isbn' => '9780563528883'],
        ['name' => 'The Silmarillion', 'writer_name' => 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 'isbn' => '9780007120604'],
        ['name' => 'Animal Farm', 'writer_name' => 'George Orwell', 'isbn' => '9780140862515'],
        ['name' => 'It', 'writer_name' => 'Stephan King', 'isbn' => '9781441738707'],
        ['name' => 'The Art of Deception', 'writer_name' => 'Kevin Mitnick', 'isbn' => '9780470249321'],
    ]);
    foreach ($books as $book) {
        Book::create($book);
    }
```

Migration Code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('writer_name');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->string('isbn')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the `DatabaseSeeder` class, you may use the `call` method to execute additional seed classes. Using the `call` method allows you to break up your database seeding into multiple files so that no single seeder class becomes overwhelmingly large. Pass the name of the seeder class you wish to run:

```
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    $this->call([
        UserSeeder::class,
        PostSeeder::class,
        CommentSeeder::class,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: if this won't help, run: composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify which seeder file to run by command `php artisan db:seed --class=yourseedername`
Also in you seeder code you are inserting same data twice one by DB query and another from Book model. So you are duplicating same data twice. I believe an error should be thrown as column violation saying integrity constraint violation as isbn for books are unique.

Comment: If the there is no error then you want to add unique() constraint tof isnb column in your migration file.