# laravel 7x can't seeding

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to seed with models in laravel.

I'm using xampp to create database and check data. Table is creating but seeding is not working. (seems working on batch)

Here is code, please check. Thanks :)

**Migration Sheet (2020_08_08_092121_create_books_table.php)**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('writer_name');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('isbn')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

**Model Sheet (Book.php)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    
}
```

**Seed Sheet (BookSeeder.php)**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class BookSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $books = [
            ['name' => 'Harry Potter', 'writer_name' => 'J.K. Rowling', 'isbn' => '9780739360385'],
            ['name' => 'Game of Thrones', 'writer_name' => 'George R.R. Martin', 'isbn' => '9780739308684'],
            ['name' => 'Harry Potter', 'writer_name' => 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 'isbn' => '9780563528807'],
            ['name' => 'The Lord of The Rings', 'writer_name' => 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 'isbn' => '9780563528883'],
            ['name' => 'The Silmarillion', 'writer_name' => 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 'isbn' => '9780007120604'],
            ['name' => 'Animal Farm', 'writer_name' => 'George Orwell', 'isbn' => '9780140862515'],
            ['name' => 'It', 'writer_name' => 'Stephan King', 'isbn' => '9781441738707'],
            ['name' => 'The Art of Deception', 'writer_name' => 'Kevin Mitnick', 'isbn' => '9780470249321'],
        ];
        foreach ($books as $book) {
            Book::create($book);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an almost exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340636/cant-seed-the-database-in-laravel, but from different Users...

Comment: yeah it's a teamwork

Comment: Any reason you couldn't have just updated the other question? As it stands, that one now serves no purpose. Try to keep SO clean; if you don't need that old question, please delete it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the fields on the model fillable before you can use the `::create()` method like that.

Have a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'writer_name',
        'isbn'
    ];
}
```

A little side note. If your table name was not the pluralised version of your model `Book / books`, then you would also need to specify a table name on the model. But in your case Laravel expects the table to be named "books", so you are good. Just though I would mention this, in case you don't already know.

Comment: i just added it: protected $table = 'books'; protected $fillable = [ 'id', 'name', 'writer_name' ]; , it still doesn't work. we're trying to catch bugs or anything.

Answer (score 1):

add `$this->call(BookSeeder::class);` this line in your run() function inside `seeds/DatabaseSedder.php` file

like this

```
public function run()
{
   ...
   $this->call(BookSeeder::class); //attach this line
}
```

then run this command on cmd

```
php artisan db:seed
```